# Creating an ASP.NET web site and moving a Windows Server VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

For a class project I created an ASP.NET web site using Visual Studio. I also have a virtual machine running Windows Server 2012 R2.

My project instructions say I simply need to "copy your code [from Visual Studio] to the Windows Server wwwRoot folder [on the virtual machine]."

This does not work for me.

When I try and access the page from "localhost/theNameofMyProject" I'm getting the same error as this post on the msdn forums (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/755e8e5a-3446-42df-b4bd-5545431873c1/vstudio-local-host-runs-ok-but-aspx-not-on-server?forum=wcf) but the solutions suggested there aren't helping me.

The website works when run in Visual Studio on my host machine and the IIS server seems to be working (it displays the default windows screen when accessed through "localhost" on the virtual machine).

What is the correct way to take my website from Visual Studio and host it on my Virtual Machine IIS server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Only hosting website on virtual machine is not enough. The machine should have appropriate.NET framework installed on it. And the app pool of your website should be pointing to proper aversion of .NET.

Comment: Also you should not copy the complete project with of visual studio to the target server. You should create a build package if web site using publish wizard from visual studio. That will create a folder with all the necessary files which required to run the website. You copy that folder on their virtual machine and create website pointing to that folder there.